# How to change dropdown menu depending on table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hello all: i have  2 dropdowns list that populate themselves from two different TABLES.
The first TABLE
(ID|Project_Name|isActive).
And the second TABLE is for users 
(Project_Id|Name)
I want to show the options from the second dropdown according on what is selected from the first one. 
For example in the first TABLE i have 3 Projects:
1:Project1
2:Project2
3:Project3

And on the second TABLE which is for users: The user has an id that depends on the project from first TABLE:
User A works on Project1
User B works on Project1
User C works on Project2

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeProject()
{
alert(document.getElementById("ProjOptionId_id").value);
}
</script>
<form method="POST" action="page.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php Insertprojects(); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<?php InsertUsers(); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
function Insertprojects()
{
$Search ="SELECT * FROM proj_database";
$query= mysql_query($Search);
echo "<select name=\"ProjOptionId\" id=\"ProjOptionId_id\" onchange=\"changeProject()\">";
$bFirstLoop=0;
while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
echo "<option value=\"$Row[ID]\">$Row[Project_Name]</option>";
if($bFirstLoop==0)
{
$GLOBALS['sProjectId'] = $Row['ID'];
}
$bFirstLoop++;
}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

I made the javascript function to get the index of the dropdown, so i can change the second dropdown depending on the element selected.

How can i do when you select Project1 on first dropdown, to appear in second dropdown the users that works only with Project1 and so on without reloading the page.

Comment: Do you have any code you have created? I don't believe there is sufficient information here to provide an exact answer that is suitable to the stackoverflow format.

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements instead of mysql_ functions, they've been deprecated.

Comment: Is there a form submit before the second drop down or are you wanting it to be done dynamically within the page?

Comment: Ok i have edited my code, i want the second dropdown to change dinamycally, i dont know if this is possible without reloading page.

Comment: Are you able to use Javascript?

Comment: yes, but how can you get a variable from php in this case $GLOBALS['sProjectId'] that gives me the ID from the 1st TABLE (projects) to change on javascript, when combobox option is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this by jQuery:

```
$(function() 
{
$("#projectSelector").change(function() 
{
$("#customerSelector").load("getter.php?project_id=" + $("#projectSelector").val());
});
});
```

Where this is my first dropdown:

```
<select id="projectSelector" name="projectSelector">
<option selected value="base">--Select an option--</option>
<?php
/*Code to populate from Mysql query
SELECT* FROM......*/
?>
</select>
```

and the second dropdown that takes the value according on what is selected from first one

```
<select id="customerSelector">
<option>--Select an Option--</option>
</select>
```

and the getter.php is an external files that contains a varible to use when the dropdown value changes:

```
<?php
$sProjectId = $_GET['project_id'];
mysql_query = SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE tablecolum = $sProjectId;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
{
echo "<option>".$row['tablecolumn']."</option>";
}
```